# Call same method from onClick on differents components

Tags: angular, ionic2

On my `app.html` I have like a navigation drawer (`ion-nav`) where I have a button that has this :

```
<button ion-button block clear (click)="showAlert()">Alert</button>
```

I've tried to put the `showAlert()` method from `app.component.ts` but it doesn't show the `alert` either a `console.log("")`.

Is there another way to do that instead of create the same function on every component?

### Example

`app.html`

I have the `ion-nav` and I have a `Button` like this :

```
<button ion-button block clear (click)="showAlert()">Alert</button>
```

The thing is I have this `ion-nav` on every page of my app, so I want to detect the click on that `ion-nav` from all of my pages.

Comment: Where is your html and where is ts and can you please put some codes to understand. Are you calling method in same component or from parent to child or child to parent.

Comment: edites the quesiton @Ahmadmnzr